# Why doesn't my css only drop down menu work in opera for mobile?

Tags: css, opera

My menu displays in a line and then becomes a drop down menu on smaller screens. It works in every browser apart from opera for mobile. Please can someone tell me why please?

I don't understand why it doesn't work in opera? Is Opera the new IE?

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CSS Only Navigation Menu</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">About &#65516;</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">What We Do</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Portfolio &#65516;</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Web &amp; User Interface Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Illustration</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position: absolute;
}

/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
li {
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;
}

/*Style for menu links*/
li a {
    display:block;
    min-width:140px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background: #2f3036;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*Hover state for top level links*/
li:hover a {
    background: #19c589;
}

/*Style for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    color: #2f3036;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

/*Hover state for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a:hover {
    background: #19c589;
    color: #fff;
}

/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
li ul {
    display: none;
}

/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
}

/*Prevent text wrapping*/
li ul li a {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
    display: block;
}

/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/
.show-menu {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #19c589;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: none;
}

/*Hide checkbox*/
input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
    display: block;
}


/*Responsive Styles*/

@media screen and (max-width : 760px){
    /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
    ul {
        position: static;
        display: none;
    }
    /*Create vertical spacing*/
    li {
        margin-bottom: 1px;
    }
    /*Make all menu links full width*/
    ul li, li a {
        width: 100%;
    }
    /*Display 'show menu' link*/
    .show-menu {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen mobile browsers picking up the hover effect but most of the time it has some complications. The hover "state" isn't relevant on mobile devices this is causing some of your problems.

I would recommend using a little Javascript to solve the problem. You could try something like:

```
// Toggle menu
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#about").click(function(){
        $("#aboutSub").hide();
    });
});
```

In combination with the following HTML

```
<li>
    <a href="#" id="about">About</a>
    <ul id="aboutSub">
        <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">What We Do</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

In this case pressing "About" will hide the sub menu. You could run a if statement to check if the element is visible or not. You could also use ToggleClass to add a class to the element changing the state from `display: block` to `display: none`. These are just some simple solutions to fix this problem.

Hope this will get you on track :)

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to use an alternative to `hover`, as I don't really want to use javascript, as some users of the site might have it disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The current developer version of Opera has a problem with drop down menus. Maybe you ran into this.